# how to delete java 10 ?

Tags: java, macos

I hears people said that you need java 8 for React Native development.

I tried to revert from 10 to 8, they say you can't, you just have to delete 10 then install version 8.
I tried to delete version 10, no document on that, only for java version 7.

Is there anyone can help me with this?

Comment: https://it.uoregon.edu/reverting-java-windows

Comment: Personally, I do the following in console to disable temporarily a JDK. `cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/`, then `sudo mv Info.plist Info.plist.disabled`. Then MacOS can fall back to the latest enabled JDK itself.